# Will I be allowed back into Germany with an expired visa?

Tags: visa, germany

I'm currently in the US for vacation and fly back to Germany on the 20th. Unfortunately, on the 14th, my visa expired. I had applied for a new one before I left so its in progress but I've heard nothing back, and its been well over a month. I'm still employed in Germany and have a flat. Will I still be able to enter Germany with the expired visa?

Comment: You need a valid visa or residence permit. What kind of visa was it that expired, and what kind of visa are you waiting for?

Comment: Its an employment/residence visa. My work contract is good for one year, so every year I have to renew the visa.

Comment: What is your citizenship?

Answer (score 3):

You say you applied for your new visa before you left, which implies that you applied for it in Germany.  If so, you did not apply for a new visa, but rather a new residence permit.  Visas can only be sought and granted outside of Germany.

It was probably not a good idea for you to have traveled out of Germany while the application was pending, but, regardless, you won't be able to get back in without one of the following:

- a valid residence permit
- a valid visa in your passport
- a passport from a country whose citizens do not need visas to enter the Schengen area

You should call the German consulate to ask them about this.  If you don't meet the third criterion, they may be able to issue a visa so you can return to Germany and pick up your residence permit.